# Сравнение BigInteger и int, short в C#

Tags: c#, biginteger

Пытаюсь разобраться в принципе работы... На примере:

```
        BigInteger bnum = BigInteger.Parse("2443534553434233455436465677687669784354423324");
        int intnum = 131;
        Console.WriteLine(bnum > intnum); //true
```

Как происходит сравнение int, short, ushort и т.д. переводятся в тип long, который прописан в System.Numerics.

```
    public static bool operator >(BigInteger left, long right);

    public static bool operator >(BigInteger left, BigInteger right);
```

или всё таки эти типы преобразуются в BigInteger. И как вся эта магия происходит?

Спасибо!

Comment: ну если других нет перегрузок, то да, переводит в ближайштй подходящий тип. Какой ближайший - решает компилятор.

Comment: Получается в BigInteger он никак не попадёт? например, если бы не было перегрузки > < на простые типы, то компилятор бы ругался или всё таки собрался и сделал BigInteger?))

Comment: Если есть оператор преобразования из int в BigInteger, то он будет задействован, если нет - то нет. Ваш КО )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример класса с оператором преобразования и сравнения

```
class MyClass 
{
    private int _initial;
    public MyClass (int initial) => _initial = initial;
    public static implicit operator MyClass(int v) => new MyClass(v);   
    public static bool operator < (MyClass l, MyClass r) => l._initial < r._initial;
    public static bool operator > (MyClass l, MyClass r) => l._initial > r._initial;
}
```

Как использовать

```
var mc = new MyClass(1000);
Console.WriteLine(mc < 10);
Console.WriteLine(mc > 10);
```

Пример класса с перегруженными операторами сравнения

```
class MyClass 
{
    private int _initial;
    public MyClass (int initial) => _initial = initial;     
    public static bool operator < (MyClass l, long r) => l._initial < r;
    public static bool operator > (MyClass l, long r) => l._initial > r;
}
```

Использовать можно точно также

```
var mc = new MyClass(1000);
Console.WriteLine(mc < 10);
Console.WriteLine(mc > 10);
```

Comment: Да согласен - не обратил внимание...
Там в классе BigInteger определены implicit и explicit методы ))